# How to use react router server-side

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I have a web app that use react-router to routes components client-side using browserouter. But when I deploy it on Azure and refresh the page, it throws error 404 page not found. I think because it has only the client side routing system. How can I add the server side?

I tried to follow: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/static-router

But it throws this error:

> ./node_modules/react-router-dom/server.mjs
> Can't import the named export 'Action' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

This is the component where I do the routing:

```
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar'
import FootBall from './Components/Football'
import LiveMatches from './Components/LiveMatches'
import Home from './Components/Home'
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './css/index.css';
import * as ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom/server";
import {http} from "http";

function requestHandler(req, res) {
  let html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
      <App></App>
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  res.write(html);
  res.end();
}

http.createServer(requestHandler).listen(3000);

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Router>
             <Navbar></Navbar>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route path="/lega-serie-a" element={<FootBall/>}/>
          <Route path="/live-matches" element={<LiveMatches/>}/>
         
        </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: See the CRA [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#azure) specific to Azure, it may help. The general gist is that whatever server/hosting service should be serving the root index.html file for all page requests into the React app. This is so the app bundle is returned to the client and the React app loads and internally handles rendering the correct route based on the current URL.

Answer (score 1):

Single Page Applications often rely on client-side routing. These client-side routing rules update the browser's window location without making requests back to the server. If you refresh the page, or go directly to URLs generated by client-side routing rules, a server-side fallback route is required to serve the appropriate HTML page, which is generally the index.html for your client-side app.

It depends on which hosting/server are you using. For example, there is a "Fallback routes" solution in azure static websites:

[Fallback routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#fallback-routes)

Comment: I don't understand where i have to put the lines of code of the Json. 
'
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  }
}'

Comment: Please follow the instructions in the link which I sent. It says you have to create a JSON file that names "staticwebapp.config.json" in your "app_location" path. The default path is where your 'index.html' exists.